# Scrolling background like Coachella

Tags: html, css, background

I'm relatively new to the coding side of websites but pick things up quite quickly. I've been inspired by the Coachella website: https://www.coachella.com/ and I quite like how the background is stationary during the "plan your Coachella bit". I've had a good search on Google, and have managed to create a scrolling background using CSS, but I don't want the background to scroll, I want it to be stationary, but for a longer time than the height of it. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this like on the Coachella site?

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? Please.

Comment: .openday {
 height: 2000px;
 margin-left: -8px;
 width: 1900px;
 margin-top: 3025px;
 background-image: url(../Images/Open%20Day2.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-origin: content-box;
 background-clip: content-box;
 background-size: 1900px 1080px;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the following CSS which has done what I wanted it to:

```
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```